# ShrePoint Online Modern Site Does not display global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, global-navigation

I have a SharePoint online site with 5-6 Sub sites within it.All are modern sites.I have set the Global navigation setting to "Structural Navigation: Display the navigation items below the current site" with "Show Subsites" option is checked. That's it. I don't see the subsites over the global navigation over the site home page. when I go to site settings.aspx page there I can see the navigation does displays thse subsites over the Global Navigation section.

Kindly help in resolving the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue per my test.

Global navigation will not display in Modern page.

When we disable publishing feature, the top link bar works well.

Comment: Hi,
I tried to disable the Server publishing feature, still I don't see the newly added modern page links over the Global navigation.

Request you to help me on this please